# Python - HTML - Send HTML Table with CSS Style

Tags: python, html, css, csv, tabulate

I'm trying to send a email with a table as a body with some CSS configurations. For that I have the following code:

```py
import csv
from tabulate import tabulate
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib

text = """Hello, Friend.Here is your data:{table}Regards,Me"""
html = """"\
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
     .tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
     .tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;}
     .tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;}
     .tg .tg-0lax{text-align:left;vertical-align:top} 
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <table class="tg">
    <tr>
      <th class="tg-0lax">Environment</th>
      <th class="tg-0lax">Date</th>
      <th class="tg-0lax">Error_Type</th>
      <th class="tg-0lax">Error_Object</th>
      <th class="tg-0lax">Description</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-0lax">DEV</td>
      <td class="tg-0lax">15/03/2019</td>
      <td class="tg-0lax">ERROR</td>
      <td class="tg-0lax">Table</td>
      <td class="tg-0lax">More columns than expected</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>"""

with open('file.csv') as input_file:
    reader = csv.reader(input_file)
    data = list(reader)
```

However I'm facing with a problem when I add the CSS style:

```
html = html.format(table=tabulate(data, headers="firstrow", tablefmt="html"))
KeyError: 'border-collapse'
```

How can I add that CSS Style on my HTML Table?

Many thanks!!!

Comment: Laurent LAPORT's answer is correct. It is recommended to use inline styles rather than an embedded stylesheet, as email clients such as gmail will strip most css rules from the `head` tag.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use double curly-braces in oder to avoid string format interpolation.

For instance:

```html
  <style type="text/css">
     .tg  {{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}}
     .tg td{{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;}}
     .tg th{{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;}}
     .tg .tg-0lax{{text-align:left;vertical-align:top}} 
  </style>
```