# How to avoid KeyError: 'border-collapse' error while using HTML tags in python?

Tags: python, html, css, pandas, dataframe

I am getting below error while using a style tag in my HTML string.

```
df_html = html_string.format(table=df.to_html())
KeyError: 'border-collapse'
```

Here is my code :

```
filename = 'exl_sheet.xls'
df = pd.read_excel(filename)
html_string = """
<html>
 <head><title>HTML Pandas Dataframe with CSS</title></head>
  <style type="text/css">
    table {border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;}        
    th, td {text-align: left; padding: 8px;}
    tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #f2f2f2;}
  </style>
 <body>
  {table}
 </body>
</html>
 """
df_html = html_string.format(table=df.to_html())
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55211547/python-html-send-html-table-with-css-style

Comment: @radulfr Style tag becomes redundant if I use double curly braces. Please suggest some other alternative.

Comment: I don't have another solution, I thought that would work. What do you mean by redundant?

Comment: By redundant, I mean the style tags are not applied after using double curly braces.